# How to make a criteria query with 3 OR Criterions properly?

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'd like to make a criteria query with 3 OR Criterions and I dont know what is the best way to do it.

Currently I only have 2 or Restrictions.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Reader.class)
.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like(PUBLICATION_ID_FIELD, "Question",MatchMode.END), Restrictions.like(PUBLICATION_ID_FIELD, "Idea",MatchMode.END)));
```

How can I add a third one ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can either "or" one more restriction to the result:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Reader.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.or(condition1, condition2), condition3));
```

or use Disjunction:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Reader.class);
Junction conditionGroup = Restrictions.disjunction();
conditionGroup.add(condition1).add(condition2).add(condition3);
criteria.add(conditionGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this link for more detailed explanation for conjunction and disjunction

[How to use Hibernate Criteria objects for multiple and/or conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194260/how-to-use-hibernate-criteria-objects-for-multiple-and-or-conditions)

Comment: To prevent link rot, please explain the major points of what is described in your link.