# How to use Hibernate Criteria objects for multiple and/or conditions

Tags: hibernate-criteria

I need to create a Hibernate criteria restriction that ors 3 Conditions.  The problem is that the last condition is acutally to conditions using the AND operator.

My first condition:

```
Criterion startInRange = Restrictions.between("expectedStartCanonicDate", 
                                               rangeStart, rangeEnd);
```

My second condition:

```
Criterion endInRange = Restrictions.between("expectedCompletionCanonicDate", 
                                             rangeStart, rangeEnd);
```

MY third condition needs to AND the following two conditions together:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.le("expectedStartCanonicDate", rangeStart));
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("expectedCompletionCanonicDate", rangeEnd));
```

The restriction I want to do is condition1 or condition2 or condition3. I have found examples that get me close.  I can use a LogicalExpression to or the first two conditions together, however, I'm not sure how to `or` 3 conditions, particularly when the last condition is really two separate conditions '`anded`' together.

Any Thoughts?
Fred

Answer (score 47):

A sequence of restrictions linked with `or` is called a disjunction. A sequence of restrictions linked with `and` is called a conjunction.

So, what you need is

- one conjunction for your third condition
- one disjunction to link the first, second, and third conditions:

So here it goes:

```
Criterion startInRange = Restrictions.between("expectedStartCanonicDate", rangeStart, rangeEnd);

Criterion endInRange = Restrictions.between("expectedCompletionCanonicDate", rangeStart, rangeEnd);

Criterion thirdCondition = 
    Restrictions.conjunction().add(Restrictions.le("expectedStartCanonicDate", rangeStart))
                              .add(Restrictions.ge("expectedCompletionCanonicDate", rangeEnd));

Criterion completeCondition = 
    Restrictions.disjunction().add(startInRange)
                              .add(endInRange)
                              .add(thirdCondition);

criteria.add(completeCondition);
```

Comment: thanks, those two really saved my life here. your example even covered the exact problem i had, with the addition that the `expectedCompletionCanonicDate` could be null as well in my case.
So if your time-range should also fetch open frames you need to add a disjunction to the second add of the 'thirdCondition` _)

line #7 would then be
`.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.ge("expectedCompletionCanonicDate", rangeEnd)).add(Restrictions.isNull("expectedCompletionCanonicDate")));`

Comment: @JBNizet Can you please help in to add multiple Criterion on run time?

Comment: @JBNizet What is the default in add, is it and or or?

Comment: @AkhilDad if you're talking about Criteria.add(), it is "and". You could also just test it...

Answer (score 1):

```
Criteria criteriaObj = sessionselectreply.createCriteria(TaskReplyVO.class,"taskreply")
                .createAlias("taskreply.objTaskView", "taskview")
                .createAlias("objMailTo", "mailto")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("taskview.longTaskId", taskid))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("mailto.longuserid", userid));
```